# first_or_create only insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I'm using the following code in a Rails 5.2 project:

```
c = Country.where(name: "test").first_or_create

c.status = "Old"
c.save
```

This works, however, I only want to change the status when there is not a country already (so I only want to insert countries, not update). However, I also need to use `c` later in my code.

I realize I could just do an if statement, but I have to do a similar thing multiple times in my code, and it seems like a shortcut must exist.

Comment: if statement should not hurt I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`create_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-create_with) by following:

```
c = Country.create_with(status: 'old').find_or_create_by(name: 'test')
```

This will create `Country` with `status` *'old'* and `name` *'test'* only and only if it doesn't find the country with name *'test'*. If it does find the country with name *'test'*, it will not update the status.

Ultimately, it will also return the country in `c`, whether after finding or creating.

`create_with` only sets attributes when creating new records from a relation object.

Answer (score 0):

By default `where` returns array type and you will need to iterate to assign a new value.

And `find_by` returns actual object or nil.

```
Country.where(name: "nothing") => [] or [obj, ...]
Country.find_by(name: "nothing") => nil or object
```

You can use `find_or_create` option:

```
Country.find_or_create_by(name: 'test') do |c|
  c.status = "Old"
end


c = Country.find_or_create_by(name: 'test')
c.status = "Old"
c.save
```

Comment: Incorrect. By default [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.where](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) returns instance of [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first_or_create method finds the result in table and If it exists in the table, the first instance will be returned. If not, then create is called.

If a block is provided, that block will be executed only if a new instance is being created. The block is NOT executed on an existing record.

So If you only want to change status when country is created then use block with first_or_create method.

so your code looks like

```
Country.where(name: "test").first_or_create do |country|
  country.status = "Old"
  country.save
end
```